# OneToOne with composite PK with columns from related tables

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have three tables, let's say A, B and C:

```
Table A
id
country
B_id

Table B
id
name

Table C
country
name
description
```

Table C has a composite PK formed by columns: `country` and `name`.

Now I want to make a OneToOne connection from Entity of Table A to the Entity of Table C.

Entity C:

```
@Table(name = "C")
public class C {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CountryName id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;
...
}
```

And in Entity A I am trying something like this:

```
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String country;    

    @JoinColumn(updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private B b;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
          @JoinColumn(name = "country"),
          @JoinColumn(name = "B.name")
    private C c;
```

The reference to the `name` column of the `B` table it's not working. Can you help with any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: let me understand: A.country == C.country && A.country == B.name ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `@JoinColumns` should be in the class C, and the class A can use `mappedBy` element:

```
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {
    @OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "id")
    private C c;
}
```

```
@Table(name = "C")
public class C {
    @EmbeddedId
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "id.country"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "id.name")
    })
    private CountryName id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String country;    

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name= "B_id", referencedColumnName = "id",updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private B b;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
          @JoinColumn(name = "country"),
          @JoinColumn(name = "B.name")
    private C c;
```

If you want to do it bidirectional then also add:

```
@Table(name = "C")
public class C {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CountryName id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "c")
    private A a;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following mapping:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String country;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "country", referencedColumnName = "country", insertable = false, updatable = false))
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(referencedColumnName = "name", value = "(SELECT bTable.name FROM B bTable WHERE bTable.id = id)"))
    private C c;
}

@Entity
public class B implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private A1 a;

    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class C {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CountryName id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;
}

@Embeddable
public class CountryName implements Serializable {

    private String country;
    private String name;
}
```

the following code:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
b.setA(a);
b.setName("United Kingdom");
C c = new C();
CountryName id = new CountryName();
id.setCountry("UK");
id.setName("United Kingdom");
c.setId(id);
c.setDescription("Dieu et mon droit");
a.setCountry("UK");
em.persist(a);
em.persist(b);
em.persist(c);
em.flush();
em.clear();
A retrieved = em.find(A.class, a.getId());
System.out.println(retrieved.getC().getDescription());
```

prints "Dieu et mon droit". Is this more or less what you wanted?

The join cannot be achieved without Hibernate's `@JoinFormula`. JPA requires for all join columns in `@JoinColumns.value()` to reside in the same table.